# Set cookie with IP and send to new page

Tags: php

I'm trying to find a way to set a cookie that sets a user's IP and passes it to a second page displaying that IP. I'm probably missing something very small, but I've tried a few methods.

```
setcookie('user_ip', $_POST['user_ip']);
```

I should be able to use this function as well to find the IP, or is there another method that's easier to use?

```
server($REMOTE_ADDR);
```

I keep getting errors with whatever method I use. I just know I'm missing something small.

Comment: Playing around with that now.

Comment: You might want to use $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']

Comment: See my answer below. Maybe you can give some more information what you are trying to do; as you can use '$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']' at every page. A cookie can simply be deleted by the visitor; and once set the user could change IP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
setcookie('user_ip', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

Addition:
To echo the IP on the next page, use

```
echo $_COOKIE['user_ip'];
```

Comment: Ah, I see what I was doing wrong now... I knew it was something simple. Thanks, now just to add some more parameters to the cookie. :)